# How to get vBulletin last insert id

Tags: php, vbulletin

I'm trying to get the last insert id from a plugin I'm in the process of creating for vBulletin in PHP. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working... Any ideas how I go about it?

- The query is inserting fine using the `$db->query_write($sql_i);`
- The documentation I have found states that I need to use `$db->insert_id`

Full Code:

```
$sql_i = "INSERT INTO classifieds_item (".$i_fieldnames.",`date_posted`) values (".$i_values.",NOW())";

$db->query_write($sql_i);

header("location: classifieds.php?class_act=add_img&id=".$db->insert_id);
```

This is using the standard vBulletin database class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

insert_id() is a function, so

```
header("location: classifieds.php?class_act=add_img&id=".$db->insert_id());
```

should work. The crucial point is the difference between $db->insert_id and $db->insert_id().

Comment: Thanks - I can't vote you up as I'm new here but that solved it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mysql_insert_id()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

It will return the last id for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the previous `INSERT`.

Worth noting that the PHP documentation also suggests using alternatives as this method is now discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but because I am building a portable plugin I need to stick to using vBulletin classes where possible. For the native PHP functions to work I need a resource identifier which I do not have and would have to rewrite the plugin to cater for this. This is at the client's request.